# Error: "Join expression not supported"

Tags: sql, vba, excel, jet

I'm attempting to query a few named ranges in an Excel workbook using a JET Connection and am receiving an error (Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': Join expression not supported) when I attempt to add a second condition the one of the joins:

```
Dim strQuery As String
strQuery = "SELECT mrx.Underlying "
strQuery = strQuery & ",mrx.[exp] "
strQuery = strQuery & ",sum(mrx.[codc]) "
strQuery = strQuery & ",max(mapDt.[Str]) "
strQuery = strQuery & "FROM ((([dataMRX] AS mrx "

strQuery = strQuery & "LEFT OUTER JOIN [mapDt] AS mapDt on "
strQuery = strQuery & "(mrx.[exp] = mapDt.[DtNumeric])) "

strQuery = strQuery & "LEFT OUTER JOIN [mapUdl] AS mapUdl on "
strQuery = strQuery & "(mrx.[Underlying] = mapUdl.[rmpUdl])) "

strQuery = strQuery & "LEFT OUTER JOIN [dataTtm] AS ttm on "
strQuery = strQuery & "(ttm.[Underlying] = mapUdl.[ttmUdl] "
strQuery = strQuery & "AND ttm.[End Month] = mapDt.[Dt])) "

strQuery = strQuery & "GROUP BY mrx.Underlying, mrx.[exp] "
strQuery = strQuery & "ORDER BY mrx.Underlying DESC "
```

Specifically, if I remove either the first or second join condition in the last left outer join `(ttm.[Underlying] =  mapUdl.[ttmUdl]` or `tmm.[End Month] = mapDt.[Dt])` the query works fine. However with both conditions present, I get an error.

I'm using JET 4.0:

```
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
```

Comment: Try removing one of the brackets from before `FROM` and removing one from the end of the statement.

Comment: thx for the response, looks like I'm getting the same join error as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure this is correct, but it does execute with the Jet engine. Please give it a try.

```
SELECT sub.Underlying ,sub.[exp] ,sum(sub.[codc]) ,max(sub.[Str]) 
FROM (
    SELECT mrx.underlying, mrx.exp, mrx.codc, mapDt.Dt, mapDt.str, mapUdl.ttmUdl 
    FROM ( 
       [dataMRX] AS mrx 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [mapDt] AS mapDt on (mrx.[exp] = mapDt.[DtNumeric])
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [mapUdl] AS mapUdl on (mrx.[Underlying] = mapUdl.[rmpUdl])
) as sub
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dataTtm] AS ttm on ((ttm.[Underlying] = sub.[ttmUdl]) AND (ttm.[End Month] = sub.[Dt]))    

GROUP BY sub.Underlying, sub.[exp] 
ORDER BY sub.Underlying DESC
```